# If I full backup with root directories and lose owner of ext4 USB what can I recover?

Tags: partitioning, usb, permissions, backup, restore

If I use an ext4 USB and back up like my home which has root owned stuff, can I read all of it if I lose what user was used to own that USB and write to it? What about regular files under like my former user that gets lost? Could I on same computer make a same named user to get at that stuff if I reinstall Ubuntu? Does it help that I am on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460 with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS desktop and Ubuntu Pro? Does it help that I may try rsync or whatever needed to transfer?

Comment: I backup my $HOME and can re-install & get it all back..  Further, if I make a mistake or something goes wrong, I usually ensure I have backups of what I don't want to lose, then *non-destructively* re-install my Ubuntu Desktop system and do **not** expect to ever need to touch my backups  (You didn't specify if desktop or server). Your details however to me are unclear; files owned by *root* may not be safely backed up if using some user-level backup tool (under non-privileged user process), but will be if using an *elevated privilege* process... you were unclear as to what backup tool...

Comment: It is ext4, correct, because if so you mostly answered like my question?

Comment: I almost always backup my stuff to *ext4*, in fact most of my desktop systems live on *ext4* partitions

Comment: Sorry I was not entirely clear enough earlier, but that is you backup with ext4 USBs, correct?

Comment: I'd have to check what is on my many *external backup* drives; but the file-system in most (*if not all, and it could be all!*) will be *ext4* file-systems..  That is my default *fs* unless I have a specific reason to use another.

Comment: User "names" (userids) don't matter. What matters (what is stored in the inode, what is checked) is the UID and GID. They're both numeric values. UID 1000 on one system could be `walt`, and, on another system, could be `fred`. As long as the two systems are separate, ttere's no problem. Read `man 5 passwd;man getent`. Do `getent passwd $USER`.